# Does a copper or brass 1/2 or 3/4 to GHT fitting exist?

Tags: fitting, copper-tubing

I have been searching for this for some time and maybe someone else has seen one. I am looking for a normal 1/2 or 3/4 sweat to 3/4 male GHT (garden hose threaded) fitting, needs to be brass or copper.

**I need this in a GHT version.**
[image]

The closest thing I've been able to find is a 1/2 sweat hose bibb with a 3/4in GHT output, which I'm not sure I want for this but may have to work if I can't find the proper solid fitting. I can find MIP/NPT fittings but cannot find a GHT fitting and I'd prefer not to use an additional adapter if possible. Does anyone know if this fitting exists? Seems like it would be common but apparently not.

Comment: try searching instead with MPT (or FPT) to Hose fittings.

Comment: The male 3/4” NPT fitting is a garden hose size but shopping questions are off topic. I use a u604 going from 1/2 copper to 3/4 npt and it works fine.

Comment: You can either get it with a valve as a hose bibb/sillcock, or you can get sweat to MPT or Sweat to FPT and GHT to FPT or MPT - there is basically no market demand for a sweat to GHT fitting, and therefore there are none on the market.

Comment: https://thecraftsupply.com/product/3-4-copper-x-male-adapter/?sku=2159&gclid=CjwKCAiAxeX_BRASEiwAc1QdkTGxvbFpviX6MxXVGbmOC7uepl4aHtnbLetc3ylY8tlZUqE3-EMChhoCuS0QAvD_BwE

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen a GHT to copper sweat fitting, so your next best thing is sweat a copper X pipe adapter, similar to the picture, and then get a pipe X hose connection. The GHT hose connection can be bought in either 1/2 or 3/4 and in male or female threaded.